# Required jars for RestEasy Client

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, java-ee-7

I need to provide a java REST client, which should contain all required jars in one bundle. I chose RestEasy as  REST framwork, since the server application is done on a JBoss.

Nearly all examples I found so far use either an application container environment, where those libs are provided and thus only the Java EE API is needed during compile or are build with Maven and thus dependencies are resolved automatically, which maybe be a good idea and the current standard way to do it, but for project-related reasons I need the jars in a lib folder and be able to include during the build and wihtin an executable jar.

So my question is, which jars a necessary to build a simple client which can do something like that:

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(myURL).queryParam("param",
                "value");
Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("user", "abc");
Invocation invocation = builder.buildGet();
MyResponseObject response = invocation.invoke(MyResponseObject .class);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). The reason I say this, is that the main artifact you want is the [`resteasy-client`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client) artifact, but this artifact has dependencies on other artifacts. If I create a new Maven project, add only this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The project will pull in all this artifacts

[image]

But if you are not using Maven, You can download the entire resteasy package [**here**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resteasy/files/Resteasy%20JAX-RS/). It comes with a lot more than what you'll need, but it will have all the jars you see in the image above, along with some other goodies like user guides, examples and such. Base on the image above, just get the jars you need. Make sure you download the final-all version. When you unzip it, all the jars should be in the `lib` dir.

Another thing I might mention is that in order to unmarshal JSON representation into your Java classes, you might also need [`resteasy-jackson2-provider`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider). Doing the same as above, you will see these pulled in artifacts

[image]

Again, these are also include in the download. This will work in most cases, if you are using JAXB annotations (which could return XML or JSON), because of the pulled in artifact `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`, but that artifact doesn't support all JAXB annotations, so you might need to pull in the [`resteasy-jaxb-provider`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider), if need be. Again like I said, just the jackson2-provider may be enough. But in the case you *do* need the jaxb-prodiver, here's what it looks like

[image]

Again, included in the download

Comment: Both dependencies are needed. Jackson2 provider dependency also resolves message body error. This post is a timer saver

Comment: Your resteasy-jackson2-provider link points to resteasy-jackson-provider

Answer (score 2):

If you use maven in your project, you can type `dependency:tree` to see hierarchy of your dependencies. Libraries used by RestEasy will be listed in tree.

Comment: That's correct. He could also use maven-assembly-plugin and generate the bundle