# Unable to load builtin provider: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly

I'm trying to post some Objects (Strings) to a REST service deployed on WildFly application server using a Java Desktop application. 
Unfortunately, I don't have Maven available at runtime for the Client so I have to add manually the required JAR files. However even with a simple POST like this:

```
public static void testParam() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String s="DatiAtto.xml";
    WebTarget myResource = client.target(BASE_URL+"/create");
    Response rs = myResource.request()
    .post(Entity.text(s), Response.class);
}
```

I get as return: 
***Unable to load builtin provider: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider*** 
So far I have added the following JAR files to the Desktop application:

- jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar
- resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.8.Final.jar
- resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.0.8.Final.jar
- resteasy-client-3.0.8.Final.jar
- resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar

looking at the content of them, the class **org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider** should be packaged into **resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.0.8.Final.jar**. Why is not being loaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the `ResteasyJackson2Provider` is missing, it's that the class is not able to load (as it tries to register itself automatically), due to dependencies on other jars (that's why we use Maven ;-). Have a look at [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26678738/2587435). 
There you will find all the dependent jars and where you can download them all, if you don't already have then stashed away somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a **build** tool. Whether or not Maven is available **at run-time** should be of no concern to your client.

You can use Maven to build an assembly or a shaded JAR (fat jar, über-JAR) which includes your client and all transitive dependencies of RESTeasy.