# Is there a way to read the entity as jax-rs client?

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, rest-client

I just made a jax-rs service and I'm trying to convert the String I get from the service to entities. While with jax-rs everything is done automatically on the server side I assume there is a possibility to do it on the client side as well but I'm not finding it.

```
public class MyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/restapp/api/paints/1");
        Response response = target.request().get();
        Paint values = response.readEntity(Paint.class);
        response.close();
    }
}
```

this give an e:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class client.Paint
```

(It works with String).

Comment: Do you have a JSON provider?

Comment: @peeskillet I just have the resteasy client dependency on the client app. However I didn't add such thing as a provider on the server side, so I'm a bit confused about your question.

Comment: If you're using Maven, pick your RESTeasy version [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider), and add the dependency. If you're not using Maven, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26678738/2587435)

Comment: What server are yo using? If you're using Wildfly, it already has the provider.

Comment: @peeskillet that was it indeed thanks! By the way so I can kill two birds with one stone, do you know how I can transform the `readEntity(Paint.class)` to accept a list of Paint objects ?

Comment: `readEntity(new GenericType<List<Paint>>(){})`

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks, I'll accept the anwser.

Comment: @peeskillet just letting you and future readers know that I had to use another method for the list. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a JSON provider. For RESTeasy, you can see [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider) and select your version, and add the dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy3.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi you can write ReastEasy or Jersy Client to get Json from your Service.
how to write client you can follow :http://entityclass.in/rest/jerseyClientGetXml.htm