# org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/plain and type class java.lang.String

Tags: java, rest

org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/plain and type class java.lang.String

Please help to solve the issue

Provider App :

```
@Path("/payment")
public class PaymetResource {

    Object object=null;
    @Path("{type}/{gateWay}")

    public Object getResource(@PathParam("type") String type){

        if(type.equals("creditCard"))
            object = new CreditCardPaymentResource();


        if(type.equals("debitCard"))
            object = new DebitCardPaymentResource();


        return object;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CreditCardPaymentResource {

    /*
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String processPayments(){
        return "hi boss";
    }*/

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response processPayment(@QueryParam("cardNo") String cardNo,@PathParam("gateWay") String gateWay){
        String result="processed payment with Gateway:"+gateWay+" and cardNo :"+cardNo;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
        //return "processed payment with Gateway:"+gateWay+" and cardNo :"+cardNo;
    }


}
```

---

```
public class DebitCardPaymentResource {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String processPayment(@QueryParam("cardNo") String cardNo,@PathParam("gateWay") String gateWay,@QueryParam("pin") String pin){
        return "processed payment with Gateway:"+gateWay+" and cardNo :"+cardNo+"pin No"+pin;
    }

}
```

client app :

```
public class RestFirstClient{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

            ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:8081/DynamicDispatch/rest/payment/creditCard/HDFC");
            request.accept("text/plain");
            request.queryParameter("cardNo", "669888554");
            ClientResponse<String> response = request.get(String.class);
            System.out.println(response.getEntity().toString());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My program is working fine when we access the service through the url. Please help me

Url :http://localhost:8081/DynamicDispatch/rest/payment/creditCard/HDFC?cardNo=99809990876

output :processed payment with Gateway:HDFC and cardNo :99809990876

Comment: You're probably missing the resteasy-jaxrs jar in client app. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26678738/2587435) for all the jars the client is dependent on. Better to just use Maven so everything is pulled in.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, No I have included resteasy-jaxrs.jar in my client application but still its not working

Comment: Thanks for the Reply,  I have included resteasy-jaxrs.jar even though its throwing the same exception

Answer (score 0):

The combination of **content-type text/plain** and **type class java.lang.String** is handled by the **org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar** found in **resteasy-core**.

And the client is created like:

```
final ResteasyClient client =
    new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl() //
        .connectTimeout(10, SECONDS) //
        .readTimeout(10, SECONDS) //
        .connectionCheckoutTimeout(10, SECONDS) //
        .register(new StringTextStar()) //
        .build();

final ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath("whatever path"));
final CreditCardPaymentResource client = target.proxy(CreditCardPaymentResource.class);
```